# Give an alternative package to blindtext package and that generate a single page dummy text?

Tags: latex, bibliography

Give an alternative package to blindtext package and that generate a single page dummy text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of these boring dummy texts, I suggest the `duckuments` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\blindduck[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following `lipsum` package in your LaTeX document.

command:-
`\usepackage{lipsum}`

Also to add a blind document you need the command `\BlindDocument`